# General Architectural Decision Record (ADR) tool

Tags: architecture

We are considering implementing **Architectural Decision Records** (ADR) in our org. The understandable focus for the tooling I have seen assumes implementation in a per project way,  i.e. within a code repository. Many of the things we want to document ADRs for are broader systems that would not necessarily have a repository.

Do any of the tools out there produce more generalized wiki style ADR repositories independent of git or other source control? Log4Brains can publish a static site to GitLab/GitHub pages but still seems to be dependent on being part of a repo. Specifically I looked at Log4brains, adr-tools, and adrgen—they all seem to work on this assumption.

I realize we could of course use something as simple as a Google doc but I like the tools route because it enforces rigor on formatting and things like supersedence, etc. I just want to make sure I have not missed anything in terms of options, so any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We at Postel are actively working on precisely that. Postel helps engineering teams manage lifecycle of ADRs and other types of proposals, version them and much more.  Right now we're in a stealth mode, but very soon starting beta.

Please give us a follow on Twitter @PostelHQ https://twitter.com/postelHQ